# How to open HTMLHelp (.chm) file from Borland C++ Application

Tags: c++builder, chm

We have a legacy application developed in Borland C++ Builder.  Now we have updated the help file to HtmlHelp (.chm) file, we want to click on the Help button in the legacy c++ application to open the .chm file. It seems that I cannot find a good way to do this? Can anyone help?

Comment: In what format was your old help file? What version of BC++ did You used and do you have source of an application?

Comment: Our old help is WinHelp. BC++ is Builder 6. We own the source code of the C++ application. Someone mentioned in a different topic of using HtmlHelp.ocx or just use shellexecute. Can anyone show me some sample code?

Answer (score 2):

My application uses HTML Help but in a newer version of C++ Builder.

Here is a code snipit of how we include it in the main form.

```
//helpviewer
#include "HTMLHelpViewer.hpp"
#pragma link "HTMLHelpViewer"
```

In the formactivate

```
Application->HelpFile = "some drive letter:\\some directory\\somehelpfile.chm";
```

To display the help

```
Application->HelpCommand(HELP_CONTENTS,0);
```

Hope this is of some value

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked and answered many times before, with full code snippets, in the Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero forums.  Search the archives at http://www.deja.com and http://forums.embarcadero.com.

Comment: -1 Not a helpful comment. I just searched the forums and got exactly 1 hit on the word htmlhelp, which didn't solve my problem. At least provide a link(s) to support your statement.

Comment: This answer was posted 3 years ago. Embarcadero's forum server crashed a few weeks ago and all past messages were lost. But there are third-party archive sites available that have copies of past messages. Or search Google.